# How is the relation $R=\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)\}$ on the set $A=\{1,2,3\}$ transitive?

Tags: relations

A binary relation $R$ over a set $X$ is transitive if whenever an element $a$ is related to an element $b$ and $b$ is related to an element $c$ then $a$ is also related to $c$.

If I consider any two ordered pairs there is no common element.So how is $R$ transitive in the above question?

Comment: If the first pair is $(1,1)$ and the second pair is also $(1,1)$, then, yes, they have common elements.

Comment: Oh!I didn't think that way.

Comment: Your relation is equality. And equality is transitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transitivity of $R$ means $\forall x,y,z\in A\;(\;((x,y)\in R\land (y,z)\in R)\implies (y,z)\in R).$

$\forall x,y,z\in A$ is an abbreviation for $\forall x\in A\;\forall y\in A\;\forall z\in A.$ It does NOT mean $\forall x\in A \;\forall y\in A\setminus \{x\}\; \forall z\in A. $  It does NOT exclude any of $x=y, y=z$ or $z=x.$

It is analogous to the definition of $A^3=A\times A\times A=\{(x,y,z): x,y,z\in A\}.$ That is $(x,y,z)\in A^3$ iff $(x\in A\land y\in A\land z \in A).$ If $x=y=z\in A$ then we certainly do have $(x\in A\land y\in A\land z\in A)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $aRb$ and $bRc$ then $aRc$ this is the definition of transitivity. If there is no such $a,b,c$ then also statement is true . If word is important.

Comment: It's called *vacuously true* that a relation is transitive whenever the condition $aRb$ and $bRc$ is not satisfied.

Comment: @amWhy and OP:  I agree that if there is no such $a,b,c$, then the statement is vacuously true.  But there *are* such $a,b,c$ in this problem - no where  does it say $a,b,c$ are distinct.  So, for example, $1R1$  and $1R1$ implies $1R1$ is true.